# Extract specific data from SimplePie get_content object

Tags: php, preg-replace, extract, str-replace, simplepie

I have an RSS feed from which I'm trying to extract data though SimplePie (in WordPress).

I have to extract the content tag. It works with `<?php echo $item->get_content(); ?>`. It throws out all this stuff (of course this is just an entry, the others have the same structure):

```
<table><tr valign="top">
<td width="67">
<a href="http://www.anobii.com/books/Lapproccio_sistemico_al_governo_dellimpresa/9788813230944/014c5c45a7ddaab1ec/" style="border: 1px solid #333333">
<img src="http://image.anobii.com/anobi/image_book.php?type=3&amp;item_id=014c5c45a7ddaab1ec&amp;time=0">
</a>
</td><td style="margin-left: 10px;padding-left: 10px">[person name] put "[title]" onto shelf<br/></td></tr></table>
```

Though what I need is just the content inside src="" tag (image url). How can I extract only that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) (the best way):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$imgs = $doc->getElementsbyTagName('img');
$res = $imgs->item(0)->getAttribute('src');

print_r($res);
```

With a regex (the bad way):

```
if (preg_match('~\bsrc\s*=\s*["\']\K[^"\']*+~i', $html, $match))
    print_r($match);
```

Comment: So I should print $item->get_content(); on some file first?

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno: no, just replace `$html` by `$item->get_content()`

Comment: print_r($res); takes the first result starting from the bottom the the results. How can I make it start from the top?